# Is there any way to find a string from a table?

Tags: module, lua

I don't know if there's any way to find a string from a table in Lua that matches the argument for example.

```lua
function Library.Instance(object,name)
   local Explorer = {}
   local Storage = {
     "fart",
   }

   if Storage == ((theobjectname)) then
       print(object)
   end
end
```

Comment: try comparing items (not tables) `if Storage[1]==name then..`

Comment: This is a fairly trivial question, I suggest reading through [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html) to get a grasp on the basics of Lua.

Comment: There is no inbuilt function to search an array. You can however provide your array as a set (table) instead and just check if the key (the argument) exists.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement it by yourself.
Here is my version of a `tsearch()`...

```
-- tsearch.lua
local magictab = {}
function magictab.tsearch(self, searchfor, replace)
        local searchfor, replace, self = searchfor or 'Lua', replace or '<%1>', self or _G
        for key, value in pairs(self) do
                if type(value) == 'string' then
                        local found, count = value:gsub(searchfor, replace)
                        if count > 0 then
                                print('Key:', key, 'Found:', found)
                        end
                end
        end
end
-- Creating Key/Value Pairs
magictab['A Key With Spaces'] = 'Ghostbuster Goes Ghost Busting'
magictab[#magictab + 1] = 'Another Day - Another Table'
magictab[0] = 'Here I am - The Ghost Within Machine'
-- magictab.tsearch() -- Using defaults
return magictab
```

An impression typed in Lua Standalone...

```
$ /usr/local/bin/lua
Lua 5.4.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2021 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> t=require('tsearch')
> t.tsearch()
Key:    _VERSION        Found:  <Lua> 5.4
> t:tsearch('Ghost')
Key:    A Key With Spaces       Found:  <Ghost>buster Goes <Ghost> Busting
Key:    0       Found:  Here I am - The <Ghost> Within Machine
> t:tsearch('%u%l+','*%1*')
Key:    1       Found:  *Another* *Day* - *Another* *Table*
Key:    A Key With Spaces       Found:  *Ghostbuster* *Goes* *Ghost* *Busting*
Key:    0       Found:  *Here* I am - *The* *Ghost* *Within* *Machine*
```

And...
This is only one way.
...there are many.

By the way...
Above `tsearch()` gives arguments 1:1 to `gsub()`.
Therefore it could be a usefull [training function for pattern matching](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1) and replacement checks.
For example: Do you know the pattern `%f[]` is usefull for?
Or: What is a replacement function?

```
> t:tsearch('%f[%u+%l+]',function(match_not_used_here) return '>>' end)                            
Key:    1       Found:  >>Another >>Day - >>Another >>Table
Key:    0       Found:  >>Here >>I >>am - >>The >>Ghost >>Within >>Machine      
Key:    A Key With Spaces       Found:  >>Ghostbuster >>Goes >>Ghost >>Busting
> t:tsearch('%f[^%u+%l+]',function(match_not_used_here) return '>>' end)
Key:    1       Found:  Another>> Day>> - Another>> Table>>
Key:    0       Found:  Here>> I>> am>> - The>> Ghost>> Within>> Machine>>
Key:    A Key With Spaces       Found:  Ghostbuster>> Goes>> Ghost>> Busting>>
```